# Как спарсить курс криптовалюты?

Tags: javascript

Не парсит, выдает ошибку.

```
fetch('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd', { 
method: 'GET',
headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
})
```

Ошибка с сайта jsfiddle:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CORS заголовки на стороне сервера выставляют, а не в запросе передают. Если не отдается, значит проксировать через свой бэкэнд

Answer (score 1):

Вот - простой курл на php, если пишете в vsc  - там есть плагин phpserver, стаивте его, если пыха не стоит - устанавливаете её и curl на машину и запускаете страницы в браузер через этот сервер, curl - в корень проекта, данные curl под себя поменяйте, в fetch ставьте php файл, который выполняет curl, далее - как обычно.

```html
<?php


$myCurl = curl_init();
$headers = [
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("user:password") <!-- Если надо - сюда - пароль и логин  -->
];




curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://sub.interfax.kiev.ua/rss/econ.php",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
));



$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Можно опустить опцию `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true` т.к. полученный контент всё равно отправляется в ответе. Это и так происходит в стандартном поведении (без опции `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true`). В таком случае достаточно будет просто выполнить запрос и закрыть ресурс.

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке говорится о том, что сервер не рекомендует браузеру использовать получаемый контент. Более подробную информацию по этому вопросу можно найти на странице https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Это можно обойти, добавив опцию `mode: 'no-cors'` для `fetch`.

Пример Вашего кода с добавленной опцией:

```js
fetch('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd', { 
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
})
```